# convert string data type duration to date time format in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, string-to-datetime

How do I extract just the time portion of `datetime64[ns]` column formatted `1900-01-01 00:32:59` and convert it into total seconds?

I want the end result to be `1979` in seconds in this example, where we are exactly (32*60 + 59) seconds from `1900-01-01 00:00:00`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas; transform column with MM:SS,decimals into number of seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472413/pandas-transform-column-with-mmss-decimals-into-number-of-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) + [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) + [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["1900-01-01 00:32:59"]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)
                 date
0 1900-01-01 00:32:59

df['total'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['date'].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
                .dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df)
                 date  total
0 1900-01-01 00:32:59   1979
```

Or [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) + [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['total'] = (df['date'] - df['date'].dt.floor('D')).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df)
                 date  total
0 1900-01-01 00:32:59   1979
```

Or [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) + [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)

```
df['total'] = (df['date'] - df['date'].dt.normalize()).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df)
                 date  total
0 1900-01-01 00:32:59   1979
```